# LWC render logic resetting previous records

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, iteration, template

I am trying to have an LWC where the user can add rows and the new row will render fields based on the user selected value.

I have 2 issues with my LWC

1. After user selects first field picklist value the value is cleared during render process
2. I am trying to render different fields based on the picklist value Labor_Type__c but when I update the picklist value on the newly added row the previous row(s) will update to new selected  Labor_Type__c value.

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <template for:each={rows} for:item="row" for:index="index">
            <lightning-record-edit-form key={row.id} object-api-name="**strong text**Cost_Estimate_Item__c">
                <lightning-messages> </lightning-messages>
                <lightning-layout multiple-rows>
                    <lightning-layout-item size="12" large-device-size="2" padding="around-small">
                        <lightning-input-field field-name="Labor_Type__c" data-id={row.id} onchange={handleLaborChange} value={row.laborType} 
                                               variant="label-stacked" required></lightning-input-field>
                    </lightning-layout-item>   

                    <template if:false={row.laborTypeSpecific}>
                        <lightning-layout-item size="12" large-device-size="2" padding="around-small">
                            <lightning-input-field field-name="Cost_Type__c" variant="label-stacked" required></lightning-input-field>
                        </lightning-layout-item>

                        <lightning-layout-item size="12" large-device-size="2" padding="around-small">
                            <lightning-input-field field-name="Days_Per_Crew__c" variant="label-stacked" required></lightning-input-field>
                        </lightning-layout-item>
                    </template>

                    <template if:true={row.laborTypeSpecific}>
                        <lightning-layout-item   size="12" large-device-size="2" padding="around-small">
                            <lightning-input-field field-name="Cost_Type__c" variant="label-stacked" required></lightning-input-field>
                        </lightning-layout-item>

                        <lightning-layout-item   size="12" large-device-size="2" padding="around-small">
                            <lightning-input-field field-name="Number_of_Crew_Members__c" variant="label-stacked" required></lightning-input-field>
                        </lightning-layout-item>
                    </template>
                        <lightning-layout-item size="12" large-device-size="2" padding="around-small">
                            <div class="slds-p-top_medium">
                                <lightning-icon  icon-name="action:new" access-key={row.id} id={index}
                                    alternative-text="Add Row" size="small" 
                                    onclick={addNewRow}>
                                </lightning-icon>
                                <lightning-icon   icon-name="action:delete" access-key={row.id} id={index}
                                alternative-text="Delete Row" size="small"
                                onclick={removeRow}>
                                </lightning-icon>
                            </div>
                        </lightning-layout-item>
                </lightning-layout>
            
            </lightning-record-edit-form>
        </template>
        </br>

    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS

```javascript
    @track LaborType = false;
    @track selectedEstItemId;
    @track listOfEstimateItems;
    @api getObjectInfo;
    selectedItem = '';
    keyIndex = 0;
    rows = []; 
    label = {
        COST_ESTIMATE,
        COST,
        COST_TYPE,
        HOURLY_RATE,
        DAYS_PER_CREW,
        NUMBER_CREW_MEMBERS,
        HOURS_WORKED_DAY,
        LABOR_TYPE,
        ADD_ROW,
        DELETE_ROW
    }

    @track itemList = [
        {
            id: 0
        }
    ];

    @track addRow = [
        {
            id: 0
        }
    ];

    connectedCallback() {
        // Add an initial row when the component loads
        const newRow = {
                        id: this.rows.length + 1,
                        laborType: null,
                        laborTypeSpecific: false
                       };
                    this.rows.push(newRow);

    }

    addNewRow() {
           let addRow = { 
            id: this.rows.length + 1,
            laborType: null,
            laborTypeSpecific: false
           };
     
        this.rows = [...this.rows, Object.create(addRow)];

    }

    removeRow(event) {
        const rowId = event.target.accessKey;
        this.rows = this.rows.filter(row => row.id !== rowId);
    }

    handleLaborChange(event) {
        const rowId = event.target.dataset.id; 
        const selectedValue = event.detail.value;
        console.log('selectedValue ',selectedValue)
        const cm = 'Field Labor';
    
        this.rows = this.rows.map(row => {
            console.log('row.id ',row.id)
            console.log('rowId ',rowId)

            if (row.id == rowId && row.id != undefined) {
                return { ...row, laborType: selectedValue, laborTypeSpecific: selectedValue !== cm };
            }
            return row; 
        });  
    }
```

Comment: The ask is for a user to be able to add/remove rows.  Each row will create a record.  If someone has a better approach please advise.  The issue is I am trying to render fields base don the users selection of a picklist value in the component. Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep track both of records and fields in a single component becomes quickly a nightmare. I suggest to use a parent component for records and a child component for fields. This means no `data-id`, no `index`. `laborTypeSpecific` becomes a component level variable. On the other hand, this requires the child component to talk to its parent by means of events.

From the comments I have learned that records are to be inserted in one go, after the insertion of a parent `Cost_Estimate__c`. This makes  `lightning-record-edit-form` unsuitable, because [the component is for saving a single record by the click of a button](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation). Unfortunately this places the responsibility of the property bindings on the code.

The following is working. Here's the LWC I call `parent`. I added a `save` button:

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <template for:each={rows} for:item="row">
            <c-child key={row.id} row={row} onsaverow={saveRow} onaddrow={addNewRow} onremoverow={removeRow}></c-child>
        </template>
        </br>
        <lightning-button label="Save" onclick={saveAllRows}></lightning-button>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Javascript of the parent LWC, including a dummy call `saveAllRows` to Apex:

```javascript
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { saveCostEstimate} from '@salesforce/apex/CostEstimateController.saveCostEstimate';

export default class Parent extends LightningElement {

    rows = [];
    counter = 1;

    connectedCallback() {
        this.addNewRow();
    }

    saveRow(event) {
        const {row, key} = event.detail;
        const index = this.rows.findIndex(r => r.id === key);
        this.rows[index] = row;
    }

    addNewRow() {
        let addRow = { 
            id: '' + this.counter++
        };
        this.rows = [...this.rows, Object.create(addRow)];
    }

    removeRow(event) {
        if(this.rows.length === 1) return;
        const rowId = event.detail;
        this.rows = this.rows.filter(row => row.id !== rowId);
    }

    saveAllRows() {
        // TODO
        saveCostEstimate({rows: this.rows});
    }
}
```

Below the `child` LWC. I also removed `index` and `access-key` logic and promoted `laborTypeSpecific` to module level variables:

```html
<template>
    <lightning-layout multiple-rows>
        <lightning-layout-item size="12" large-device-size="2" padding="around-small">
            <lightning-combobox name="Labor_Type__c" label="Labor Type" value={row.Labor_Type__c} options={laborTypeOptions} onchange={handleLaborChange} required></lightning-combobox>
        </lightning-layout-item>   

        <template if:false={laborTypeSpecific}>
            <lightning-layout-item size="12" large-device-size="2" padding="around-small">
                <lightning-input name="Cost_Type__c" label="Cost Type" value={row.Cost_Type__c} onchange={handleCostTypeChange} required></lightning-input>
            </lightning-layout-item>

            <lightning-layout-item size="12" large-device-size="2" padding="around-small">
                <lightning-input name="Days_Per_Crew__c" label="Days per Crew" type="number" value={row.Days_Per_Crew__c} onchange={handleDaysPerCrewChange} required></lightning-input>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </template>

        <template if:true={laborTypeSpecific}>
            <lightning-layout-item   size="12" large-device-size="2" padding="around-small">
                <lightning-input name="Cost_Type__c" label="Cost Type" value={row.Cost_Type__c} onchange={handleCostTypeChange} required></lightning-input>
            </lightning-layout-item>

            <lightning-layout-item   size="12" large-device-size="2" padding="around-small">
                <lightning-input name="Number_of_Crew_Members__c" label="Number of Crew Members" value={row.Number_of_Crew_Members__c} onchange={handleNumberOfCrewMembersChange} required></lightning-input>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </template>
            <lightning-layout-item size="12" large-device-size="2" padding="around-small">
                <div class="slds-p-top_medium">
                    <lightning-icon  icon-name="action:new"
                        alternative-text="Add Row" size="small" 
                        onclick={addNewRow}>
                    </lightning-icon>
                    <lightning-icon   icon-name="action:delete" 
                    alternative-text="Delete Row" size="small"
                    onclick={removeRow}>
                    </lightning-icon>
                </div>
            </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>
</template>
```

Last but not least the Javascript of child LWC. Note how much code is spent due to the removal of `lightning-record-edit-form`; e.g. we need to explicitly initialize the picklist:

```js
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValues } from "lightning/uiObjectInfoApi";
import LABOR_TYPE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Cost_Estimate_Item__c .Labor_Type__c';
import COST_TYPE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Cost_Estimate_Item__c.Cost_Type__c';
import DAYS_PER_CREW_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Cost_Estimate_Item__c.Days_Per_Crew__c';
import NUMBER_OF_CREW_MEMBERS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Cost_Estimate_Item__c.Number_of_Crew_Members__c';

export default class Child extends LightningElement {

    @api
    row;
    
    laborTypeSpecific;

    laborTypeOptions = [];
    @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: "012000000000000AAA", fieldApiName: LABOR_TYPE_FIELD })
    laborTypeOptionsWrapper({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.laborTypeOptions = data.values;
        }
    }

    addNewRow() {
        const event = new CustomEvent('addrow');
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    removeRow() {
        const event = new CustomEvent('removerow', {
            detail: this.row.id
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    handleLaborChange(event) {
        this.row.Labor_Type__c = event.detail.value;
        this.laborTypeSpecific = this.row.Labor_Type__c !== 'Field Labor';
        this.handleChange();
    }

    handleCostTypeChange(event) {
        this.row.Cost_Type__c = event.detail.value;
        this.handleChange();
    }

    handleDaysPerCrewChange(event) {
        this.row.Days_Per_Crew__c = event.detail.value;
        this.handleChange();
    }

    handleNumberOfCrewMembersChange(event) {
        this.row.Number_of_Crew_Members__c = event.detail.value;
        this.handleChange();
    }

    handleChange() {
        const event = new CustomEvent('saverow', {
            detail: {
                row: this.row
            }
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

The `parent` uses a simpler mechanism to generate `ids`. `this.rows.length + 1` produces duplicates as soon as records are deleted that are not at the end.

The `child` doesn't try to use `id` attributes on `lightning-icon` buttons - it doesn't need any. In a LWC context, [Salesforce replaces `id`s by anything it wants](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-components-dom-work.html); don't rely on it.

Please note that I have no Cost_Estimate_Item__c on my org :-D and much of this is rather a stub. Take it with a pinch of salt. But it's hopefully enough to play and experiment :-)

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Before I try this approach.  Will creating the new records be an issue since there are 2 components?  Basically my goal is when a user hits save it would create a parent record Cost_Estimate__c and then all of the newly added rows Cost_Estimate_Item__c would be child records.  Just want to make sure this is possible using 2 components.  And can I add logic so that  the user cannot delete the last row using 2 components?

Comment: Of course this is possible with a parent-child setup. This is one of its benefits: You don't deal with individual fields (child component) where you submit all records (parent component). This division of labour facilitates adding such logic. (I'm less sure `lightning-record-edit-form` is of great use in this context, but this doubt applies to a single-component approach to the same degree. `lightning-record-edit-form` is for updating and inserting individual records.)

Comment: originally used lightning-record-edit-form since I thought it would be better to use since I was trying to use a single component.  Should I not be using lightning-record-edit-form  on the child component?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the Cost_Estimate_Item__c child records are supposed to be inserted in the wake of the insertion of their parent Cost_Estimate__c, so that this is one transaction? In that case `lightning-record-edit-form` does not give you any benefit (neither with the one-component nor with the two-component approach). The `lightning-record-edit-form` has a button that is supposed to be clicked, and it submits a single record. You could hide the button, hide the ID of the newly inserted parent etc., but this is getting very hacky.

Comment: yes this is correct.  Ideally the user add the number of Cost_Estimate_Item__c records needed.  Upon save a Cost_Estimate__c record is inserted and the user input will create the child Cost_Estimate_Item__c records.  In theory I guess I could create the Cost_Estimate__c prior to the user starting their input of the     Cost_Estimate_Item__c.  Would that make a difference?

Comment: Yes. You could then ask the user to press a "save" button for each Cost_Estimate_Item__c item, making sure they are wired up to their parent (Id). But this is probably still not what you want, because a single "save" button for all records seem to make more sense. Unfortunately each `lightning-record-edit-form` comes with its own submit button. Have a look at "Creating a Record" in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152181/discussion-between-felix-van-hove-and-phuc).

Answer (score 0):

Below are some suggestions to address the issues:

1. **Value Cleared During Render Process:** Ensure that each `lightning-input-field` is bound to a unique property of an object in the JavaScript array that represents the rows. This way, when the component re-renders, it maintains the state of each input field.
2. **Rendering Different Fields Based on Picklist Value:** Instead of using a single **LaborType** property for all rows, each row should have its own property to track the selected `Labor_Type__c` value. This prevents changes in one row from affecting others.

Use the below approach for your component:

```
// In your JS
export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
  rows = []; // Initialize an array to hold the row data

  connectedCallback() {
    // Add an initial row when the component loads
    const newRow = {
                    id: this.rows.length + 1,
                    laborType: null,
                    laborTypeSpecific: true // Default to true or false based on your logic
                 };
                this.rows.push(newRow);
  }

  removeRow(event) {
    const rowId = event.target.accessKey;
    this.rows = this.rows.filter(row => row.id !== rowId);
  }

  handleLaborChange(event) {
    const rowId = event.target.dataset.id; 
    const selectedValue = event.detail.value;
    const cm = 'Labor';
 
    this.rows = this.rows.map(row => {
        if (row.id === rowId) {
            return { ...row, laborType: selectedValue, laborTypeSpecific: selectedValue !== cm };
        }
        return row; 
    });
  }

// ...your other methods ...
}
```

In your HTML, you would iterate over the rows array to render each row, and use data-id to associate each `lightning-input-field` with the corresponding row:

```
<template for:each={rows} for:item="row" for:index="index">
  <lightning-record-edit-form key={row.id} object-api-name="Estimate_Item__c">
  <!-- ... other fields ... -->
  <lightning-input-field field-name="Labor_Type__c"
data-id={row.id}
onchange={handleLaborChange}
value={row.laborType}
required>
  </lightning-input-field>
  <!-- Render other fields based on row.laborTypeSpecific -->
  </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

Make sure to replace **data-id** with the appropriate attribute to store the row ID, and update the **handleLaborChange** method to use this ID to find and update the correct row.

Comment: thanks for the response Tushar.  I need to review this and see if I can get this to work.  I also added addrow function to the original code above if you can review.  In you response would <template if:false={LaborType}>  reside inside the lightning-record-edit-form?  Thanks

Comment: Tushar, do I need to remove the original lightning-layout & lightning-layout-item syntax?

Comment: Tushar I think the rendering is now working.  I am unable to add or remove rows.  For adding I tried to mimic what is happening on load and that does not work.  But if I click the and and then the remove the new row shows.  Of if I click the add button and update the Labor field the new row shows. Any thoughts? Cheers

Comment: @Phuc, If possible can you please share the full code?

Comment: I updated the original code.  thx

Comment: Not sure why top of my html code not showing

Comment: I updated the JS to add a row and was able to get this to work.  Interesting think is happening.  If I add a row and populate and then add another row and populate the Labor Type field it update the first row to match second row Labor Type.  And it only does it for the first time.  if I update the first row to its original value and then update the second row the first row remains.

Comment: I was able to get the add row to work.  Now looking to get delete to function

Comment: It doe snot appear that the I am not seeing which row is actually selected